# Sending XML over HTTP with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am dealing with a third-party api here and I need to send HTTP Post request represented in XML. How should I go about doing this in Rails? Which library/method if any will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try net/http package, in particular [post method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html#M000683). There're examples too.

As to xml part, you can send any data you want as long as it's string.

Comment: so I can just pass the xml string to the second argument?

Comment: @denniss Never used post method myself, but according to the docs - yes. Anyway, it doesn't hurt to try :)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be Net::HTTP library: http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html